# How to fetch record from Sqlite by comparing two dates

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I searched heavily about this on Internet but din't got a solution yet.

Basically I want to populate records between two dates from my sqlite database to my custom android listview.

I know the fact that SQLite doesn't have a dedicated DATETIME type. Normally what people do is make sure they store the date as a formatted string that is consistent; for example, YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss. If you do so, as long as you're consistent, then you can compare dates directly.

However my query returns incorrect records.

These are the queries that I tried:

```
 public Cursor getBhattiNamesByDate(String fromDate, String todate, SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    /*String query = " SELECT * FROM "+ AddBhattiContract.AddBhattiItems.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "
            +AddBhattiContract.AddBhattiItems.COL_1+" BETWEEN '"+fromDate+"' AND '"+todate+"'";*/

    String query = " SELECT * FROM "+ AddBhattiContract.AddBhattiItems.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "
            +AddBhattiContract.AddBhattiItems.COL_1+" >= Datetime('"+fromDate+"') AND "
            +AddBhattiContract.AddBhattiItems.COL_1+" <= Datetime('"+todate+"')";

  /*  String query = " SELECT * FROM "+ AddBhattiContract.AddBhattiItems.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "
            +AddBhattiContract.AddBhattiItems.COL_1+" >= '"+fromDate+"' AND "
            +AddBhattiContract.AddBhattiItems.COL_1+" <= '"+todate+"'";*/

    cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
    Log.e("TagWastageCursor","true");
    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to save the dare as a timestamp (String), and then when you query, just parse those timestamps as long, and then you can compare.
Timestamp is the number of seconds from 1 January 1970.

Comment: Do you have any example i can refer to??

Comment: is it count of seconds or milliseconds ?, also i suggest using `INTEGER` not text, and thus no need to parse when query

Comment: It is the number of SECONDS, and it is better to save the timestamp as an String because you need to parse it as a Long. Long can hold more values than INTEGER, so you could hit an error if you did that.